# CSS setting height of flex containers

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 3 main div in my HTML with ids(header, flavors & purchase).  All of these 3 div are flex containers. I am trying to set the height of each div but so far I have not been able to do it.

This is my CSS code (height values are set as example, they are not the actual values I want to set):

```
#header {
  background-image: url("resources/skylight.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 55px;
}

#flavors {
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#purchase {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a snippet with your CSS, I've just added some background color to easy visualization...

```css
#header {
  background: red;
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 55px;
}

#flavors {
  background: aqua;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#purchase {
  background: lime;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="flavors">
</div>

<div id="purchase">
</div>
```

All heights works just fine, could you give us more information?

Comment: I could show you my HTML but here it says that its too long (to post here in the comments).

Comment: This is a link to a github repo with some code added to < id ="header"> .  The problem is that elements on the first div (header) start to go to the second div.     [Github](https://github.com/NaranjoJorge/pruebas/tree/master)